# TeXMaker: Compiling as Latex or pdfLatex?

Tags: pdftex, texmaker

If compiling the MWE as `pdfLatex` all is good.  Compiling as `Latex` raises compilation ERROR `! LaTeX Error: Cannot determine size of graphic in M51.jpg (no BoundingBox)`, although a pdf output is produced.

To add to the confusion the `TeXMaker` logfile says for both `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018/W32TeX)` rather than `TeX` for one and `pdfTeX` for the other.

This may just be yet another ploy to confuse lesser minds, it is even difficult to turn it into a question. This seemed to be one: "If a document includes any `.png`, `.jpg` or `.pdf` files compile as `pdfLatex`". But if continued: "… else, also compile as  `pdfLatex` because it is clearly an improvement on `Latex`." the question is no more. And why would I want to search a very large project for the occurrence of `.png`, `.jpg` or `.pdf` files to decide how to compile it?

So, when to compile as `Latex` in preference to `pdfLatex`, and why? That's the question. And it may well relate to an idiosyncracy in `TeXMaker`.

Apologies, I don't know how to supply the graphics file, but those wishing to compile the MWE may plug in any `.png`, `.jpg` or `.pdf` available.

```
\documentclass{article}
% RN. 13 March 2019
%=======================
\usepackage{graphicx}
%-----------------------
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=12cm]{M51.jpg}
\caption{Messier 51 and Companion}
\label{xxx}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Pdftex can compile to two output formats: pdf (pdflatex) and dvi (latex). Use the first if you don't know what dvi is for - normally that's the right choice. I haven't used latex earnestly for years now.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer So, if the objective is to produce pdf, use pdflatex. Latex only if dvi is required. I would be happy to tick this off as the answer, if so presented.

Comment: you have tagged the question with texmaker but that is not involved at all, that's just the editor you used to write  the source file

Comment: dvi is almost never required in itself it is an intermediate format designed to be transformed so dvips to get postscript dvipdfmx to get pdf dvisvg to get svg etc.

Comment: @David Carlisle Point taken, but I thought it worthwhile to have a stab at TeXMaker for offering the `Latex` option and then associating it with `pdfTeX`. Then again, I am just stabbing at the surface of things and in near complete darkness.

Comment: The LaTeX option is useful for compiling pstricks documents. And TeXmaker has nothing to do with it, because TeX distributions link the DVI compilation to pdfTeX n DVI mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application pdftex  can compile to two output formats: `pdf` and `dvi`.

`pdf` is an end format. `dvi` is only an intermediary format. With drivers like dvips, dvipdfmx, dvisvg it has to be processed further.

When using `pdflatex` you are running `pdftex` with the format `latex` in the `pdf` output mode.

When using `latex` you are running `pdftex` with the format `latex` in the `dvi` output mode.

The two output mode differ in their capabilities. As you discovered including `jpg` or  `png` directly requires the `pdf` mode. On the other side things like pstricks or psfrag need dvi mode.

Use the `pdf` mode if you don't know what dvi is for – normally that's the right choice.